# VS 2017 - C# - How do I connect to DB2 db with a packageset

Tags: .net, db2

How can I define a packageset in C# code when connecting to, opening, and reading from a DB2 database? I'm able to connect to and open a DB2 from my connectionstring that doesn't have a packageset defined. I'm told I HAVE TO HAVE the packageset defined in the connectionstring. Anything I attempt to add the packageset definition in the connectionstring, it throws an invalid parameter error when attempting the connection.

I've been unable to locate examples on how to specify the packageset in my connectionstring when reading from a DB2 db.

In web.config:

In my app:

```
    using IBM.Data.DB2;
    String MyDb2ConnectionString = getConnectionString(false, "WPBAdmin").ConnectionString;
    using (IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection cn = new IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection(MyDb2ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command cmd = new IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command(SQLCall, cn))
        {
            IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataReader MyDb2DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (MyDb2DataReader.Read())
```

The getConnectionString method retrieves the connection string entry from web.config.

When I don't include a package set, I'm able to connect to and open the DB2 db but throws the error "ERROR [42501] [IBM][DB2] SQL0551N "(user id)" does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform operation "EXECUTE PACKAGE" on object "NULLID.SYSSH200" when I attempt ExecuteReader() on a table. My local DB2 expert tells me because of this error, I have to include the packageset definition in the connectionstring.

I've burned off too much time on this and I have to get this resolved.. I searched and searched any/all sites I can find and coming up with nothing.

HELP ME PLEASE!!!

Comment: If you know the name of collection needed, you may try to add the following to your connection string: `...;CurrentPackageSet=mycollection;`

Comment: The connection string got lost when I posted my orig question. In web.config: <add name="WPBAdmin" connectionString="Server=ddcs.xx.yyyy-dns.com:50010;Database=DBPG;User ID=user;Password=pwd"/>. I have tried including the CurrentPackageSet parameter in the connection string to no avail. If I do, it throws an "invalid parameter" error.

Comment: Strange enough. CurrentPackageSet is one of the allowed keywords of the [DB2Connection.ConnectionString property](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClassConnectionStringProperty.html). What's your db2 platform, version and fixpack?